# PayPal bug? Sandbox (particularly IPN) does not work

Tags: paypal

A few (probably 2) days ago I tested PayPal Sandbox IPN to my server and it worked.

Today I made a few test (sandbox) payments and have not received any IPNs.

Also I tried to refund a sandbox payment and saw at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/il/cgi-bin/webscr :

> Sorry — your last action could not be completed ... We are unable to
>   complete your request at this time. Please click Retry or try again
>   later. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Message 3004

Does this mean that PayPal sandbox is broken right now?

Comment: "Receive IPN messages" was disabled for some reason.

Comment: "We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment."